# Install Error ver 1.8.1.0

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0

Yesterday I created a new database, downloaded ver 1.8.1.0, and did a fresh install. However, I repeatedly got an error that I cannot get past.

```
a:5:{i:0;s:259:\"Error in file: \".../app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/sql/catalog_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.0.9-1.6.0.0.10.php\" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table \'catalog_product_entity_group_price\' already exists\";i:1;s:1164:\"#0 .../app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception(\'Mage_Core\', \'Error in file: ...\')
#1 .../app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb(\'upgrade\', \'1.6.0.0.3\', \'1.6.0.0.18\')
#2 .../app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb(\'1.6.0.0.3\', \'1.6.0.0.18\')
#3 .../app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 .../app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 .../app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 .../app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 .../index.php(87): Mage::run(\'\', \'store\')
#8 {main}\";s:3:\"url\";s:36:\"/index.php/install/wizard/installDb/\";s:11:\"script_name\";s:10:\"/index.php\";s:4:\"skin\";s:7:\"default\";}
```

Comment: Are you sure that during installation you use empty data base? Double check that please.

Comment: I tried to install quite a few times, but yes I emptied the database every time. As I said, the first install was with a database I had just created.

Comment: The error is in the message: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'catalog_product_entity_group_price' already exists so the database is not empty when magento tries to create this table. This problem can not be reproduced.

Answer (score 2):

Just got this reply from DreamHost:

> Thanks for contacting us. Unfortunately we don't support installing
>   Magento on the shared server:
>
> http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Incompatible_applications
>
> You will need to upgrade a VPS to be able to install this:
>
> http://wiki.dreamhost.com/VPS
>
> Once you upgrade to VPS it might be able to install. If you have any
>   other questions let us know we be happy to answer them for you.